# Network drives shortcuts on desktop , howto do it correctly?

Tags: networking, drive, shared-folders

How can I do to make available a network drive on the desktop as I do with  windows?

I mean to put just a link on the desk that gives me the access to the network folder, 
I'd like it capable to keep the credentials so that the user doesn't have to write them down each time the start the PC.

I tried something like this:

1) I created a folder on this position  /mnt/Disk02 and set persmissions to chmod 777

2) On fstab I wrote the following:

smb://"netresource"/share  /mnt/Disk02   ext4 defaults

3) I've made a shortcut for Disk02 on the desktop.

Obviously on restart ubuntu failed to mount the share because i didn't know where to put the credentials.

What is the corret way to do this?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, I think you forget to **mount** your path. `sudo mount smb://"netresource"/share /mnt/Disk02 ext4 defaults`. I could help you , if you were more informative and specific. Thank you.

Comment: Galaxy, thank you for answering me, I thought that writing the mounting parameters on /etc/fstab would be enough to mount the network folder at OS startup. The network folder is a smb share and not nfs. What could I have missed ?

Comment: Well my friend, Truly I have no clue. It could be many things. Do you want to share from Ubuntu to Windows or the inverse? secondly, did you check the 139/tcp smb port? open or not?.

Comment: tcp 139 is open,  I'm using a ubuntu client 12.04 and trying to connect to another ubuntu client which has a shared folder, If i put the credentials when requested while using the " connect to server" option I do have access

Comment: sorry If i mess while assigning points... I'm new to this forum, I have to get little used to it

Comment: Emanuele, you'll get used to it very soon, believe me. Enjoy!